# Extracting Salesforce reports fields using the API

Tags: salesforce, salesforce-rest-api

I would like to extract Salesforce reports fields using the API. The only place I have found that info is by calling the describe route for the report within the [salesforce reports and dashboards rest api](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.api_analytics.meta/api_analytics/sforce_analytics_rest_api_getbasic_reportmetadata.htm#analyticsapi_basicmetadata).

Within that route I can get detail info about each column:[image]

My issue is that API calls are limited to:

- 500 synchronous queries per hour
- 1200 asynchronous queries per hour

As I need to regularly fetch more then 25k reports, I need to find another solution.

Do you know if there are any other way to get that info?

Maybe via SOQL using the rest API?  I have checked the report Sobject, it does not give info about report fields.

Comment: These limits are from [https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.api_analytics.meta/api_analytics/sforce_analytics_rest_api_limits_limitations.htm], they refer to report _runs_. Describe is a metadata call, not running the report. Thus _on paper_, the report run limits  do not apply. As always with Salesforce and limits, you'll have to try this and see how far it'll take you.

Answer (score 1):

Back at the time when I used the Salesforce API a lot, it was simply unavoidable to work around quite a few imposed limitations.

Having that in mind, perhaps an acceptable workaround for the limitation you described would be to cache the fetched report field information locally, and do the fetching only once per report, i.e. only when the required field information isn't already present in the local cache.  I suppose that the reports you fetch repeatedly don't get their layout changed, which in turn should make it possible to rather easily reuse the locally cached report field data.

Using a local cache would provide additional benefits, by reducing the number of required API calls and speeding up the overall report fetching.  It all adds up quickly when you fetch over 25k reports repeatedly.

Comment: @Elie Ladias Please, let me know if my answer requires further clarification.